# SwiftUI @FetchRequest property wrapper not updating Views with Coredata Background Context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, combine

I have a view binded to a @FetchRequest property wrapper.
When changes are made to Core Data with Main Context, views are updated with the corresponding @FetchRequest property wrapper. 
However, when changes are made to Core Data with Private BackgroundContext, the view is not reacting to @FetchRequest.
Is this a bug with @FetchRequest ?

Comment: Same here, i guess it is by design? Or am I missing something? If you think about it it makes sense.